# Azure Web App - Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-postgresql, wiki.js

I have created the Azure Postgres SQL Server and Web app with docker image following the official site of Wiki JS installation: https://docs.requarks.io/install/azurewebapp

Configured the web app with same information given in the above site:

[image]

After configuring, restarted the web app. But still, I'm getting this error;

[image]

even though I select basic plan of web app at yesterday, it worked. It shown the administrator page of wiki js but from today, it is giving me application error.

Comment: I did not find the Docker image option in publish, and instead, I only found the container [option](https://i.imgur.com/QqAEMJz.png).

Comment: Apologies for delay. @AsleshaKantamsetti. It's a docker based web application, you'll find the options during web app creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate the issue, I have created an Azure database for postgres with Basic pricing tier as recommended the wiki.js official docs.
[image]

- Allow all the Public access in networking of this Postgres SQL server.
- The other resource is Azure web app with Docker wiki image and B1 app service plan:
  [image]

[image]

- After creation of web app, configured the application settings as shown in the Wiki.js-Azure web app installation document:

[image]

- Restarted the web app after configuring the application settings.

Next part is Installation of Azure web app with Wiki.js:
When I launch azure web app public URL in the browser, it taken so much time because it is hosted in basic b1 plan which is of 1.75 GB RAM.

- To test whether this site is working, I did ping in command prompt - it is working successfully;

[image]

Also, I have received the same error you got in the browser:
[image]

This is because it hosted in the basic b1 app service compute where it is having less RAM to load. So, I did wait for 10 to 15 minutes and finally it shown the result as expected (Wiki.js Installation and local admin account creation page):

[image]

***Note***:

1. For the 1st time only, it takes more time to launch the instance and the web application.
2. Even when you stop the server and start again next day, it will take some time to load the instance and launch the web application.

*Reference: https://docs.requarks.io/install/azurewebapp*